# Looking for an Applescript to find files and move them to different folder

Tags: find, applescript, move

I'm trying to find a script to find and move files to a different folder.

I've got a folder with hundreds pictures like this:

```
PA-600-01.jpg, PA-600-02.jpg, PA-600-03.jpg, PA-600-04.jpg, PA-601-01.jpg, PA-601-02.jpg, PA-601-03.jpg, PA-602-01.jpg, PA-602-02.jpg, PA-602-03.jpg, PA-602-04.jpg, PA-602-05.jpg
```

I want to move all the pictures with `PA-600` (`so PA-600-01.jpg, PA-600-02.jpg, PA-600-03.jpg and PA-600-04.jpg`) on a folder (new or already existing, the easier...) named `PA-600`, move all the pictures with `PA-601` (`PA-601-01.jpg, PA-601-02.jpg and PA-601-03.jpg`) on a folder named `PA-601`, move all the pictures with `PA-602` (`PA-602-01.jpg, PA-602-02.jpg, PA-602-03.jpg, PA-602-04.jpg and PA-602-05.jpg`) on a folder named `PA-602`... until `PA-699`

I tried to move a file but not a group of files:

```
tell application "Finder" make new folder at alias "Macintosh HD:Users:AirYoSo:Desktop:600-699" with properties {name:"PA-600"} copy file "Macintosh HD:Users:AirYoSo:Desktop:600-699:PA-600-01.jpg" to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:AirYoSo:Desktop:600-699:PA-600" end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea how to do it in applescript, but this is quite trivial to do in bash, which you have installed on your Mac:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=600; c<=699; c++ ))
do
  echo "Processing PA-$c"
  mkdir -p PA-$c
  mv PA-$c-*.jpg PA-$c/
done
```

Save this to a file, for example `script.sh`, copy the file to the directory with your jpg files, and run it like this, in Terminal (replace /Users/lionel/files with the real path to your files):

```
$ cd /Users/lionel/files 
$ bash script.sh
```

Comment: Thank's piopuk, but I copy your code on TextEdit to save it to a file (so I've got a .txt I changed on .sh). I've got this script.sh on my folder but when I want to run it Terminal tell me "command not found" or "No such file or directory". Otherwise, are you sur it's "mv PA-$c-*.job"... or "mv PA-$c-*.jpg" ?

Comment: Corrected the file extension, of course it's about `jpg` files. When you open Terminal, make sure you are in the same directory as the files, use `cd`

Comment: hallelujah !!! It's exactly that !... Thank's a lot !... I love you !!! I need to learn this kind of thing, it's magic... Sincerely, thank you very much, it's really cool. See you and have fun ! [Un oeil qui traine... / On the look out...](http://www.unoeilquitraine.fr)

Comment: I don't know how to close the post, but right know I go to bed !... Thank's again piokuc...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set myFolder to (choose folder)
set pFolder to POSIX path of myFolder
set folderNames to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & quoted form of pFolder & " \\! -name \".*\" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | grep -Eo PA-[0-9]{3} | uniq")

repeat with aFolder in folderNames
    (do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (pFolder & aFolder))
    tell application "System Events" to move (every file of myFolder whose name begins with aFolder) to (pFolder & aFolder)
end repeat
```

EDIT
If you want to hard wire the path to the folder you can use:

```
set myFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:YoSo:Desktop:test"
set pFolder to myFolder's POSIX path & "/"
set folderNames to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & quoted form of pFolder & " \\! -name \".*\" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | grep -Eo PA-[0-9]{3} | uniq")

repeat with aFolder in folderNames
    (do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (pFolder & aFolder))
    tell application "System Events" to move (every file of folder myFolder whose name begins with aFolder) to (pFolder & aFolder)
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank's adayzdone... But it's doesn't work... If I put "Macintosh HD:Users:YoSo:Desktop:test" instead of (choose folder) it's create a folder on my Desktop named testPA-001 (PA-001 is the first file in my test folder PA-001-01.jpg) and then I've got an error message but I think the script it's close by the solution... Otherwise the script of piokuc work good. Thank you...

Comment: Hi. The first script was meant to be run as is. If you want to hard code the path to your folder try the second script.

Comment: Yes !!! Cool guys !... It's exactly what I want to do too. Two way to do, it's great. Thank's really very much for your reactivity and to have edit your codes you adayzdone and you piokuc, it's cool. See you and have fun ! http://www.unoeilquitraine.fr