# (Applescript) Rename and Move / Organize Files to Subfolders

Tags: applescript, assets, automator, file-organization

> Edit: I have already created the subfolders beforehand using automator.

I am a designer that is currently designing for Android. I use Sketch App to export all my assets so that they will have equivalent suffixes (e.g. -xxxhdpi, -xxhdpi, -xhdpi, -hdpi, -mdpi).

example of files:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMEZU.png)

example of folders:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTkr0.png)

What I'm trying to do is to move all these assets to subfolders (/xxxhdpi, /xxhdpi, etc.) and trim their suffixes.

Having zero knowledge in programming/applescripting, I tried to use Automator. But I was stumbled upon its limitation for relative paths. After searching for a lot of resources (including  [Looking for an Applescript to find files and move them to different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076940/looking-for-an-applescript-to-find-files-and-move-them-to-different-folder) and [Applescript: Create folders/subfolders and move multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527505/applescript-create-folders-subfolders-and-move-multiple-files)). It's kinda confusing because I can't quite figure out what those lines are doing. But I came up with this

```
tell application "Finder"

    set assetsFolder to (target of front Finder window) as text
    do shell script "cd " & (quoted form of POSIX path of assetsFolder) & "; "
    set selectedItems to selection

    repeat with this_item in selectedItems
        if this_item's name contains "-xxxhdpi" then
            set the theName to this_item's name
            set the theSource to "-xxxhdpi"
            set the theReplacement to ""
            move this_item to folder "xxxhdpi" of folder assetsFolder
            set name of this_item to my replace(theName, theSource, theReplacement)
        end if
    end repeat

end tell

on replace(theString, theSource, theReplacement)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSource
    set theItems to every text item of theString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacement
    return theItems as Unicode text
end replace
```

I realize that this only works for "xxxhdpi" case because I want to test it first. In the later time, I would like for this script to have other cases to apply for the rest of suffixes (I'm sorry if my English is bad).

The script itself is working fine for renaming and moving. But I can't get them to work together.

Right now, the problem is within this two lines:

```
set name of this_item to my replace(theName, theSource, theReplacement)
move this_item to folder "xxxhdpi" of folder assetsFolder
```

Either the files are renamed, but failed to move,
or the files are moved but failed to be renamed.

Also, I have tried to search for plugins to do this exact thing (organizing android assets) but I had no luck. Either I got help for writing this applescript, or someone will tell me an equivalent plugin that will do the job.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your script probably fails because folder "xxxhdpi" does not exist in assets folder. so there are 2 solutions : 1) easy, you make sure to create all subfolders in asset folder before you start the script (sub folders xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi ). 2) you change your script to add a check if subfolder exits and if not create it. indeed option 1 is much easy !

Comment: Hello pbell, thank u for your response! I forgot to tell that I have already created the subfolders. So the script works but just for one condition (either renaming or moving).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, the script assumes that the name of the subfolder is always the portion between the (last) hyphen and the dot before the name extension and there is always at least one hyphen in the file name.

The script uses the command line interface `ditto` which is able to create intermediate directories on-the-fly. It separates name and extension of each selected file and strips the subfolder name from the file name. It's not necessary to create the subfolders "manually".

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedItems to selection
    if selectedItems is {} then return
    set parentFolder to POSIX path of (container of item 1 of selectedItems as text)
end tell

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "-"}
repeat with anItem in selectedItems
    set {fileName, fileExtension} to splitNameExtension(anItem)
    tell text items of fileName to set {prefix, suffix} to {items 1 thru -2 as text, item -1}
    set newFilePath to quoted form of (parentFolder & suffix & "/" & prefix & fileExtension)
    set sourceFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (anItem as text)
    do shell script "/usr/bin/ditto " & sourceFile & space & newFilePath & "; /bin/rm " & sourceFile
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID

on splitNameExtension(aFile)
    set {name:fileName, name extension:fileExtension} to aFile
    if fileExtension is missing value then return {fileName, ""}
    return {text 1 thru ((count fileName) - (count fileExtension) - 1) of fileName, "." & fileExtension}
end splitNameExtension
```

Comment: OMG!! This is exactly what I want to achieve! I'm scanning through your codes though I don't understand any single thing :)) But anyway thank you very much!!! You've helped me saving countless hours on preparing assets. Thank you!